# My armature moves, but the mesh won't

Tags: armature, parent, rigify

[image]

[image]
I applied a parent with auto weight and now only my bones are moving, also the location of my rig was incorrect and I corrected it but it still doesn't work.
This is the link to download the file from my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wO2UdJqrPru5JX1kNk2srDQtp6nf3HjA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Apply the rotation and scale of both the armature called *rig* and the object called *Plane*, recalculate the normals of *Plane*, merge by distance with a *Merge Distance* of 0.001, parent *Plane* to *rig* (*With Automatic Weights*) and it works.